# android return null after fetching from db Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, arraylist

I am trying to add items to the list view dynamically. But, I am getting a run time exception.Please help. Is there a problem with the global variable "values"? I tried to debug by printing the logs and I am able to see the values stored in the variable . the problem happen when it return result (i use it since i get info from database )

it fetchs well from data base but when it goes to return result in try block
int jumps to onther return statement at end of function and then it crashes

code

```html
public class choose_buffet_items extends AppCompatActivity {
    String []categouries;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT=2000;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    private boolean loggedIn = false;
    String type;
    String result;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_buffet_items);
        new JSONParse().execute();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.buffet_list_view, categouries);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_buffetitem);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String s =(String)adapter.getItem(i);
                if(s.equals("Drinks"))
                {
                    Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(choose_buffet_items.this, buffet_drinks.class);
                    startActivity(numbersIntent);
                }
                else if(s.equals("Cakes"))
                {
                    Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(choose_buffet_items.this, buffet_cake.class);
                    startActivity(numbersIntent);
                }
                else if(s.equals("Appetizers"))
                {
                    Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(choose_buffet_items.this,buffet_appetizers.class);
                    startActivity(numbersIntent);
                }
                else {Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(choose_buffet_items.this, buffet_lunch.class);
                    startActivity(numbersIntent);}

            }
        });


        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(choose_buffet_items.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Upadting Data");
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(choose_buffet_items.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();


        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {



                String login_URL = "http://2f179dfb.ngrok.io/getcat.php";
                try {

                    //Fetching the boolean value form sharedpreferences


                    URL url = new URL(login_URL);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                    result = "";
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result += line;
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    Log.e("RESULT", result);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                    JSONArray result1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
                    categouries=new String[result1.length()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < result1.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = result1.getJSONObject(i);
                        String category = c.getString("buffCategory");
                        categouries[i]=category;
                    }

                    return result;


                }
                catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
            }




        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            pDialog.dismiss();



        }
    }
}
```

logcat

```html
12-25 02:45:27.532 7109-7109/com.rematchka.weddinghall E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.rematchka.weddinghall, PID: 7109
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rematchka.weddinghall/com.rematchka.weddinghall.choose_buffet_items}: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
                                                                             at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
                                                                             at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)
                                                                             at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:137)
                                                                             at com.rematchka.weddinghall.choose_buffet_items.onCreate(choose_buffet_items.java:49)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
12-25 02:45:27.962 7109-7473/com.rematchka.weddinghall E/RESULT: {"result":[{"buffCategory":"Drinks"},{"buffCategory":"Cakes"},{"buffCategory":"Appetizers"},{"buffCategory":"Lunch"}]}
```

Comment: add logcat , so people can see where the crash is

Comment: it crash when it return result

Comment: in doInBackground function

Comment: what do you want do in background to return, because your result variable is holding Json string, if it is directly to be passed to onPostExecute(), then why are you parsing json in doInBackground

Comment: im supposed to send string saying paring was successful but i havent edit it yet as it want to display certain msg in onPostExecute() upon the string

Comment: just initialize result with empty string when you declare it ..

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: I added logcat.

Answer (score 1):

This particular exception ("storage == null") is thrown when the array parameter passed to ArrayAdapter(Context, int, T[]) is null.

In this line in the oncreate method:

```
   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.buffet_list_view, categouries);
```

Categouries is null, you need to initialize it and only then do that line.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `List<String>` instead of a `String[]`, ya know?

Anyways, you are assuming an AsyncTask completes immediately. It does not.

Your array is null when you put it into the adapter.

Instead, call the AsyncTask, but don't use the data until it is ready

```
public class choose_buffet_items extends AppCompatActivity {
    String []categouries;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_buffet_items);
        new JSONParse().execute(); // Let this work in the background...

        // adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        //        R.layout.buffet_list_view, categouries);
```

set the adapter when the list is not null in onPostExecute

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(choose_buffet_items.this,
            R.layout.buffet_list_view, categouries);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Note: If you made your `AsyncTask` use `<Void, Void, String[]>`, (`Void` becuase you have no parameters or progress to monitor), then you could `return` the categories string array. Right now, you return the raw JSON string but never even use it in onPostExecute